# How to tell Sympy that one symbol is "greater than other"

Tags: sympy

Suppose I have two symbols

```
x,y=symbols('x y')
```

My objective is to tell Sympy that x is always greater than y (x>y). Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly. The [assumptions module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html) does not support relations, and it's not (yet) integrated with the rest of SymPy anyway, so its assumptions won't help you, say, simplify an integral.

The workaround is to introduce a symbol expressing the difference of two symbols, and declare that to be positive. For example,

```
y = symbols('y')
p = symbols('p', positive=True)
x = y + p
```

Now SymPy knows that x > y:

```
>>> (x > y).simplify()
True
```

How useful this is in computations that involve x depends on whether doing  `.subs(x, y + p)` will turn it into something that simplifies.

It's often easier to directly replace a condition with True or False, as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49184913).

Comment: Has there been any progress made with this? I would like to pass the assumption that a symbol x is in some interval [-y,y] i.e. -y <= x <= y.