# conds='none' in Sympy does not work

Tags: sympy

I have the following integral

```
x,x1,x2,t=symbols('x x1 x2 t')
f=t*x1*x2*(x-t)**(-Rational('0.5'))
integrate(f,t).simplify()
```

The result of this is a piecewise function

```
Piecewise((2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-I*t**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - I*t*x*sqrt((t - x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*I*x**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), Abs(t/x) > 1), (2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-t**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - t*x*sqrt((-t + x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*x**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), True))
```

I want to ignore the first case, so the solution would be to do

```
integrate(f,t,conds='none').simplify()
```

But this doesn't change the output, which is still

```
Piecewise((2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-I*t**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - I*t*x*sqrt((t - x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*I*x**2*sqrt((t - x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), Abs(t/x) > 1), (2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(-t**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - t*x*sqrt((-t + x)/x) + 2*t*x + 2*x**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - 2*x**2)/(3*(t - x)), True))
```

How can I ignore the conditions then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason that `conds` does not affect this integral is that the conditions are not convergence conditions, but rather conditions that affect the form of the integrand. The documentation of `conds` specifically refers to conditions for convergence.

> Definite improper integrals often entail delicate convergence conditions. Pass conds=’piecewise’, ‘separate’ or ‘none’ to have these returned, respectively, as a Piecewise function, as a separate result (i.e. result will be a tuple), or not at all (default is ‘piecewise’).

You can get rid of the case you don't want by replacing its condition with False.

```
>>> integrate(f, t).subs(Abs(t/x)>1, False).simplify()
2*sqrt(x)*x1*x2*(t**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) + t*x*sqrt((-t + x)/x) - 2*t*x - 2*x**2*sqrt((-t + x)/x) + 2*x**2)/(3*(-t + x))
```

Comment: You have the reason, but then how can I tell Sympy that the x>t so this does not happen?